# Enabling auto scroll in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way that we can enable auto scroll in Visual Studio Code? I have been looking in the settings but could not find anything(unless i missed something).

I am reviewing a log file and as it gets updated, its refreshed on my side. But it is not showing the latest logs but just stays where my cursor was and highlights everything that gets populated after that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Had the same problem but did not find a setting within VS Code.

However there is an extension for VS Code:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pejmannikram.vscode-auto-scroll

Works quite well for me.

Comment: The extension's ID is "auto-scroll" but the name is "AutoScroll" ... don't use the hyphen when searching for it. :)

Answer (score -2):

There's now a built in VSCode setting - you can untick Smart Scroll option (output.smartScroll.enabled).

As described here:
[VSCode: Turn auto scrolling permanently ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855587/vscode-turn-auto-scrolling-permanently-on#62141125)

"An option to turn off the smart scroll feature was included in one of the recents update (probably in the March 2020 update, I didn't found this on the changelog), see more: issue #69480

Since then, I've been able to "save" the scroll state, try this:

Go to File > Preferences > Settings (or Ctrl + ,)
In Features > Output, disable Smart Scroll option (or search output.smartScroll.enabled)"

Comment: This only effects the Output pane. OP's question is about scrolling a file that is open in the editor, being written to by another process. The equivalent of tail -f /path/thefile.log