# VSCode: Turn auto scrolling permanently ON

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is there any way to force the auto-scrolling option of the Output panel permanently enabled? 
At the moment I have to click on the lock button every time I build my project to disable the scroll lock or better to say enable the auto-scrolling feature and this is so annoying.

I took a look at the settings but couldn't find any relevant parameter there.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69480#issuecomment-556935592) in the vscode project about this behavior.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

An option to turn off the smart scroll feature was included in one of the recent updates (probably in the March 2020 update, I didn't find it in the changelog), see more: [issue #69480](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69480)

Since then, I've been able to "save" the scroll state, try this:

1. Go to **File > Preferences > Settings** (or Ctrl + ,)
2. In **Features > Output**, disable **Smart Scroll** option (or search **output.smartScroll.enabled**)

Tested with VSCode version 1.45.1 and CodeRunner 0.10.0

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer twice. This behaviour of VS Code is a massive pain and I couldn't figure out for the life of me why the output window only _sometimes_ scrolled.

Comment: @SRSR333 I'll upvote it for you. It got me half way to what I was looking for. I want it to auto scroll, AND in some way indicate it has done so. My sass compiles but its instant and I see no change in the output window because the last message is identical. I wonder if there's some way to indicate this as I use it to verify the compiler ran and Im not just wasting my time hard refreshing a thousand times

Comment: I hate those "smarts" controls that pretend to be what does not is neeeded to be

Answer (score 1):

> Smart scrolling allows you to lock scrolling automatically when you
> click in the output view and unlocks when you click in the last line

So clicking on the last line will auto scroll to the last line. I made a habit of doing that. Of course disabling Smart Scrolling is the permanent solution.

Comment: its been irritating me for years. I think everyone did that

Comment: Seems for me the disable Smart Scrolling fixes it partially, only when the window has focus.  Is it possible to keep the the scroll bars visible, i.e.  "Inactive Window Color"...?